# Pyspark java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z

Tags: windows, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, pyspark

- I want to write Pyspark Dataframe to S3 Path.Currently I am using Spark-3.0.0-preview version, Python 3.7.4 version and Hadoop 2.7.4 version on Windows 10.
- The AWS credentials and endpoint is set as follows(The bucket created is in us-east-2 region):

  ```
  spark.sparkContext.setSystemProperty("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", 
  "true")
  spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com")
  spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", access_key)
  spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", secret_key)
  ```
- The dataframe I want to write is as follows:

  ```
    r1 = sc.parallelize([(1,'madhu')])
    schema = ['id','name']
    df3 = spark.createDataFrame(r1,schema)
    df3.write.csv("s3a://my_bucket/e.csv")
  ```
- I get following error(But 'e.csv' directory gets created in bucket 'my-bucket' ):

  ```
    ERROR Utils: Aborting task
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
  ```
- Though I am succesfully able to read and create pyspark dataframe over file from this bucket using,

  ```
    df2 = spark.read.csv("s3a://my_bucket//b1.csv")
  ```

Comment: What is `%HADOOP_HOME%` set to?

Comment: Thank you. %HADOOP_HOME% is set to ->  "C:\hadoop-2.7.4"

Comment: What issues? You included no details.

Comment: Hello @kichik I have now given detailed information about the issue.

Comment: I am not able to save my Pyspark dataframe to S3. I am able to save it to local though. But I am getting error java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z

Comment: Were you able to figure out a solution for this issue?

Comment: No I was not able to resolve this issue